# Anyone interested in the audio from Stack Overflow DevDays 2009 - Austin?

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009, devdays-austin, audio

**Edit:** There looks to be enough interest to make this effort worthwile.  Check out the new article for the DevDays audio.  I will be updating that post as new presentations are available.

> [DevDays Austin audio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26587/devdays-austin-audio)

I took a bunch of audio yesterday and I'll put it on my blog if anyone wants it.  I tried to take some video but it didn't really turn out that well.  Hopefully I can get the slides from some of the speakers.

Interested?

Here's the speaker list: http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/events/austin/

EDIT: I thought this went without saying, but I'll say it anyway.  I'll stream/let you download the audio files for free.  No gimmicks, no advertisements, no catch... I just want to share the great content (especially to those of you who couldn't make it).

**Update:** I emailed every speaker and asked explicit permission to post their talk.  Jason Cohen already gave his approval and I'm waiting on everyone else.

Comment: Is this...legal?

Comment: @Thomas good question, I don't know why it wouldn't be...  I'm going to be asking everyone for a copy of their slides anyway, so I guess they could always ask me to take it down (which I would, without hesitation).  That's kind of the point of the presentations though, to share knowledge.  But - admittedly - I am working off of an assumption.

Comment: Well Joel+Co have an interest in people paying to go to the next dev days - they are losing out if people decide to listen online instead of paying to go (Yes at $99 everyone is going to go if there is an event locally). Also the speakers are paid to appear and give these talks - they could lose out if you listen to them online rather than pay to go to a conference they are presenting at.

Comment: I'm not saying that it *is* prohibited in this case but it definitely *can* be. Many speakers do not allow their talks to be recorded and re-broadcast in their entirety. I would go as far as to say that, for more-popular speakers, re-broadcast is prohibited more often than not.

Comment: @mgb that is a good point, although people like @alex were never going to go anyway, and now they can benefit from the knowledge shared at DevDays.

Comment: @Robert good point, I'm going to email each speaker individually and let them know what I'm planning.  This way, I can get slides etc... from everyone.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: It might be quicker to e-mail Joel Spolsky. He'll know what sort of agreement they have about re-broadcast.

Comment: Please seeeeeeed!

Comment: If you get permission it's probably fine to post it, but you may want to wait til all the DevDays are done as a courtesy to Joel and team!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I's say a lot of people would be interested in this. I for one can't come to any of the DevDays (the closest on is 1700 km away), but I'd like to hear what's been talked about.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.  I just wanted to ask around first as a sanity check.  If it helps one person then I'll do it.

Comment: Yeah, even I would *love* it ... I'm two continents away from the nearest devdays... :(

Comment: check post update

Comment: Thank you! I know what I'll be doing today :)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, I for one would be interested! (I just hope it's ok with the speakers and organisers to publish them.)

Comment: check post update

Answer (score 1):

Now if someone would just post the keynote video of Joel abusing his employees like a high school track coach.

Comment: haha, no joke.  That was hilarious.

Comment: check the post update if you're interested in the audio.