# DevDays Austin audio

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009, audio, devdays-austin

Where can I get audio from DevDays 2009?

Comment: no problem, I hope you like it.  But, you should thank the folks who were gracious enough to allow their talks to be posted.  They are the ones that came up with the great content, I'm just the guy who recorded it.

Comment: Upload the Joel audio! Ask him again! :)

Comment: I'd love to but I wouldn't feel right about not getting permission first, especially since this was a paid event.  I'm sure he got the email so if he doesn't respond it's no big deal.  It was a good talk though.

Comment: Still no Joel audio?

Answer (score 2):

> **Update 10/24/2009:** All of the Austin talks have been uploaded.  Enjoy!

I am in the process of uploading the audio from the DevDays Austin conference and should have everything finished by the end of the week.

I am going to create a separate post for each speaker and include the audio, any other material they send me (PowerPoint slides etc.), and a quick writeup of the talk.

I've received explicit approval from all of the speakers except Joel Spolsky (who hasn't responded yet.)  This means that I won't be uploading any of Joel's audio until I hear from him.

**Uploaded Talks:**

[Jason Cohen: Why Code Reviews Don't Have to Suck](http://cubeantics.com/2009/10/devdays-austin-jason-cohen-on-why-code-reviews-dont-have-to-suck/)
[Damien Katz: CouchDB](http://cubeantics.com/2009/10/devdays-austin-damien-katz-on-couchdb/)
[Jonathan Sharp: jQuery](http://cubeantics.com/2009/10/devdays-austin-jonathan-sharp-on-jquery/)
[Peter Mourfield: ASP .NET MVC](http://cubeantics.com/2009/10/devdays-austin-peter-mourfield-on-asp-net-mvc/)
[Jonathan Johnson: iPhone](http://cubeantics.com/2009/10/devdays-austin-jonathan-johnson-on-iphone-development/)
[Eric Jones: Python](http://cubeantics.com/2009/10/devdays-austin-eric-jones-on-python/)

*NOTE:* I will update this post every time I upload a new talk.

I really hope you all enjoy this, especially those of you who are unable to make any of the DevDays meetings.  I wish I could have captured some good video of DevDays but the quality of the video would have been poor due to the lighting and I couldn't find a good spot to record that wouldn't have annoyed everyone behind me.

**Update 10/21/2009:** Added the Jonathan Sharp (jQuery) presentation
**Update 10/22/2009:** Added the Peter Mourfield (ASP .NET MVC) presentation
**Update 10/22/2009:** Jeff posted some San Fransisco audio on the [Stack Overflow Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/podcast-71/#comment-40666)
**Update 10/22/2009:** Added the Jonathan Johnson iPhone Development presentation
**Update 10/23/2009:** Added the Eric Jones Python presentation

**Main Link:** http://cubeantics.com

Comment: The uploaded talks links appear not to be working.

Comment: @John: Comment ping the OP, as he was the originator of the links.